# Customized <input type=“file”>?

Tags: html, css

I need to add in my form a few customized `<input type=“file”>`
[image]

I tried to use this code

```
<div id="upload-file-container">
    <input type="file" name="pic[]" class="photo" value="Add photo" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#upload-file-container { 
position: relative; 
width: 50px; 
height: 20px; 
overflow: hidden; 
} 

#upload-file-container input  { 
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
font-size: 20px; 
opacity: 0; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
border: none; 
width: 50px; 
height: 20px; 
}
```

but my inputs just became invisible.
http://jsfiddle.net/FXTCg/4/
How to make visible input title "Add photo"?

Comment: For secure reason you can't change the value of that file type

Comment: They are invisible because you told them to be (`opacity: 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/mxq9R/ . Your input need to be invisible `opacity: 0` becuase you cannot apply any style or custom text in it. You need to put your visible content underneath it